# Android - Remove GridView item from inside getView()?

Tags: android, gridview

I need a way to remove an Item from the GridView but this must be done from within the getView() method inside my custom Adapter. Here is my GridView:

**Activity:**

```
    ...
    String[] newList;
    newList[0] = "Item 1";
    newList[1] = "Item 2";
    newList[2] = "Item 3";
    ...
    GridView GV = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gv);
    GV.setAdapter(new Adapter(getActivity(), newList));
    GV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, 
            View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

**Adapter**

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflator;
    private String mEntries[];

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView myTextView;
    }

    public Adapter (Context context, String[] entries) {
        mContext = context;
        mInflator = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mEntries = entries; 
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mEntries.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.gvitemlayout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.myTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.list.removeItem);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String string = mEntries[position];
        String[] data = string.split("\\.");

        if (data.length < 2) {
            TextView itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.list.itemName);
            itemName.setText("");
            TextView itemClass = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.favlist.itemClass);
            itemClass.setText("");
            holder.myTextView.setText("");
            TextView itemNone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.list.itemNone);
            itemNone.setText("No Items");
        } else {
            TextView itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.list.itemName);
            itemName.setText(data[1]);
            TextView itemClass = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.list.itemClass);
            itemClass.setText(data[0]);
        }

        final int info = (Integer) getItem(position);
        holder.myTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                SharedPreferences sP = mContext.getSharedPreferences("fav", mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Boolean b = sP.getBoolean(mEntries[info], false);
                if (b == true) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sP.edit();
                    editor.remove(mEntries[info]);
                    editor.commit();

                    // REMOVE ITEM CODE NEEDED HERE

                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Hope this makes it easier to understand what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did, there was no need to initialise the 'adapter' variable. Inside the `getView()` simply do this:

1. Remove the Item from the list that was used as the data source.

So. if you want to remove Item 2 from the list

`String mEntries[] = ITEM1, ITEM2, ITEM3, etc`

Do this:

```
String newList[] = new String[mEntries.length - 1]; 
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < mEntries.length; i++) {
    if (mEntries.length - 1 > 0) {
        if (mEntries[i] == mEntries[1]) { // mEntries[1] as the range starts from 0, so 1 would be ITEM2
            // SKIP IF MATCHES THE ITEM YO WANT TO REMOVE                       
        } else {
            newList[count] = mEntries[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
}
mEntries = newList; // save the new list into mEntries
notifyDataSetChanged(); // notify the changes and the listview/gridview will update
```

Comment: very good answer sir.but sometimes its showing arrayindexoutofboundexception

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is very possible. You didn't give enough code for it to be clear exactly what's happening, but the code above you posted won't work unless the remove button is an entire view returned by getView in the adapter.

Your getView in your adapter will need to look something like this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_item, null);
        }

        Button removeButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.remove_button);
        removeButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.mThumbIdsList.remove(position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: The code I pasted is not my Code, i found it on StackOverflow. What I need to know is what goes inside the onClick. How do I remove the item using `int position`? I have `GridView gv = (GridView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid);` inside my onClick, what next?

Comment: You don't remove the child view from the GridView. You remove the item from whatever your adapter's data set is and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter. Without seeing any of your code, that's about the best explanation we can give you.

Comment: @Extremis my answer correctly answers that. In the getView method of your adapter that is feeding views to your GridView, when the "Remove View" button is pressed, that is the position you want to end up removing. Notice how in the signature of the method I declare the position as final, and then in the on click listener I use the position to remove the data that needs to be removed, and redraw the Grid. This is how you do that, however obviously you'd have to adapt this code to your own use. I assumed the data backing your Adapter was in fact the adapter.mThumIdsList.

Comment: That's what I need help with. How do I get the "adapter" variable initialised? Also, I have posted an EDIT in the main post above. PLease see my current code.

Comment: @Extremis That may be well beyond the scope of this question. When I say initialize, I mean calling new MyAdapter(); or whatever you'd call your adapter. You could look at this question for an example of someone using a BaseAdapter (my go-to adapter) to create the views for a ListView, which as far as the adapter is concerned, is the same.

Comment: Which question. No link provided

Comment: @Extremis I guess it took the link out. That's weird. Either way, it's not necessary. It appears your question has the full Base Adapter in it. Now that you are showing more information, getActivity() is returning null wherever you are calling GV.setAdapter(new Adapter(getActivity(), newList));. Call it in the onCreateView method instead of wherever you are calling it. That really goes for all of that code. You listed a lot of code as being in an Activity, that's actually in a Fragment it looks like. What method is that stuff being called in?